# Trouble runing a c++ project on Windows (Was coded on Linux)

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Ok guys, I've been using Ubuntu for a while, so I've been coding all my projects using NetBeans on ubuntu. Now, due to external causes I need to code on Visual Studio/Windows.
I know migrating projects from one OS to another may be problematic so I made a new c++ project on Visual and included all the .cpp files from my project.
I'm having the next issues when I run it, this is the output:

```
'proyecto01datosWIN.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'proyecto01datosWIN.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'proyecto01datosWIN.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'proyecto01datosWIN.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'proyecto01datosWIN.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

I know it may be caused by some library, these are the libraries I'm using in different files:
    iostream,
    fstream,
    sstream,
    vector,
    cstdlib,
    string,
    algorithm,

The program reads a .txt and generates a list of objects.
I'll been trying to figure it out but haven't been able to fix it!
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is this only when compiling a debug build?

Comment: you have visual studio.  **set a breakpoint in main, and step into the program.**  The output above is simply debug output from the debugger, telling you it can't find debug information for some of the assemblies it loads.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal (it also does it for my c++ apps), there's no pdb files for the kernell32 dll. This should not impact your application.

Comment: But it doesn't run, is may be another thing tho

Comment: @JoséDelValle Probably, is there a compilation error? What is it?

Comment: Just the output I posted, that's all I know about it's "condition"